# Stuck trying to use a variable in python 3 Tkinter UI

Tags: python

I'm stuck trying to use the variable I need the name of the path of the folder that was selected to print after the predict flag on the exec path line

```
def clicked():
    folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
    exec(Path("whatevascript.py --weights weights.h5 predict (folder_selected)").read_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python Anonymous Function (Lambda function)

You will need to use a lambda expression as an argument to the command parameter that calls this clicked function in the button that was clicked, and it would go something like this

```
Button(root, text="Click me", command=lambda :clicked(VARIABLE))
```

As you can't pass arguments to a the function pointer you are giving to the command parameter